# SpriteKit PhysicsBody is not applying for my bezier curve

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

Here is the test code:

```
var paths = UIBezierPath()
var bottomLeft = CGPoint(x: dim.minX, y:dim.minY)
var bottomRight = CGPoint(x: dim.maxX , y: dim.minY )
var topRight = CGPoint(x: dim.maxX, y: dim.maxY )
var topLeft = CGPoint(x: dim.minX, y: dim.maxY)


paths.moveToPoint(bottomRight)
paths.addLineToPoint(topRight)

paths.moveToPoint(topRight)
paths.addLineToPoint(topLeft)

paths.moveToPoint(topLeft)
paths.addLineToPoint(bottomLeft)

paths.moveToPoint(bottomLeft)
paths.addLineToPoint(bottomRight)


var n = SKShapeNode(path: paths.CGPath)
n.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
n.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromPath: paths.CGPath)
shapeLayer.addChild(n)
```

It draws a standard rect. I will add some curve in the middle from topRight to topLeft points, but I wanted to test it with simple rect. I am testing the collision with a ball and it seems to be only colliding with the line from bottomRight to topRight and ignoring the rest. Does anyone have a idea on whats going on here?

[image: Physic issue: Physics is not applied fully to middle rectangle in gray]

Comment: skView.showsPhysics=YES; can help you out you can see thin physics bodies around your shapes

Comment: @dragoneye Thanks for the tip. It looks like the physics body applied is incorrect. Do you have any other suggestions? I've updated the original post with a image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not sure about the issue with bezier path and the physics collision setup code needed, I was however able to get it working with using raw paths and adding lines:

```
    var polygonPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(polygonPath, nil, bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(polygonPath, nil, topRight.x, topRight.y)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(polygonPath, nil, topLeft.x, topLeft.y)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(polygonPath, nil, bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(polygonPath)

    var n = SKShapeNode(path: polygonPath)
    n.strokeColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    n.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromPath: polygonPath)
```

That sets up proper physics collision bounds. Although this solves my issue, any insight on why the original code was not working with bezier path would be great. Thanks.